# Python - Remove dictionary from list of dictionaries if list of strings not in dictionary key

Tags: python, string, list

```
results = [
        {'id': 1, 'text': 'String 55 - 1' },
        {'id': 2, 'text': 'String 3 - 2' },
        {'id': 3,  'text': 'String 5 - 4 - 1'}]

str = [' 5 ', ' 4 ']
```

I want to remove from `results` every dictionary that doesn't contain every string in the `str` list in the `text`. At the moment I can do it with one condition, for example:

```
results[:] = [d for d in results if lst[0] in d['text']]
```

But this wouldn't check if `' 4 '` is in text too.

Comment: Its clear that you need 2 loops.

Comment: I think you named your list of strings `str` but in the comprehension you use `lst`. Could you maybe [edit] your question so it's verifiable? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use [`all`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) to test if *all* the items in the list are in a dictionary value and use that in the *filter* of your list comprehension:

```
lst = [' 5 ', ' 4 ']
results[:] = [d for d in results if all(i in d['text'] for i in lst)]
print(results)
# [{'text': 'String 5 - 4 - 1', 'id': 3}]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use an [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) in the condition of your comprehension:

```
results = [
        {'id': 1, 'text': 'String 55 - 1' },
        {'id': 2, 'text': 'String 3 - 2' },
        {'id': 3,  'text': 'String 5 - 4 - 1'}]

strs = [' 5 ', ' 4 ']  # you shouldn't name it "str" because that's a builtin function

>>> [dct for dct in results if all(substr in dct['text'] for substr in strs)]
[{'id': 3, 'text': 'String 5 - 4 - 1'}]
```

---

You could also use [`set.issubset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set.issubset) and [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) instead:

```
strs = {'5', '4'}  # this is a set!

[dct for dct in results if strs.issubset(dct['text'].split())]
```

This will check if your `['text']` splitted at whitespaces contains all the characters in `strs`. Depending on the length of the `text` and the number of items in `strs` this could be faster than the `all`-approach.